# Why was Rahm Kota accepted into the Jedi Order?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi

### Introduction

General Rahm Kota was a Jedi Master and General during the Clone Wars and later appeared in the *Star Wars: the Force Unleashed*, both as enemy and ally of Galen Marek.

His Wookieepedia [article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rahm_Kota) states that Mace Windu met him on his home planet and brought him back to Coruscant where, despite his high age, he was accepted into the Jedi Order and trained by Master Yoda. The article does not, however, provide any explanation for why he was accepted.

Yoda himself has stated, on multiple occasions that people should not be trained as Jedi due to their high age ([Luke Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker) and [Anakin Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker) come to mind) and yet he accepted Rahm Kota who was of an age with Luke, and a lot older than Anakin.

### Question

**Is there an explanation, of any canon level, to why Rahm Kota was accepted into the Jedi Order?**

Direct answers are of course preferable, but I highly welcome well-founded assumptions and similar.

Comment: The problem isn't age per se, it's innate qualities that are settled in by that age.

Comment: Neither of the two Force Unleashed books has anything on the topic, FYI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been unable to find anything in either the new or Legends canon explaining WHY an older candidate like Kota was allowed to join. However, we can make some assumptions based on the reasons why Jedi typically don't accept candidates above a certain age:

- Familial connections - children above a certain age tend to become extremely attached to their family members. It is difficult, if not impossible, to remove this sense of attachment later.
- Habits - children form habits, both good and bad, early on. The younger the candidate, the less "bad" training needs to be undone. Essentially, the Jedi want an empty cup that they can fill themselves... not a cup already half-filled by someone else.
- Emotional training - a large part of early Padawan training is emotional control. Once a child has already learned to embrace their emotion, and favor a specific emotional state (such as a temperamental child embracing anger), it becomes very difficult to teach them otherwise.
- Patience - It can be very difficult for an older child or young adult to fully embrace the life of a Padawan or Jedi. Extreme patience is required.

Now, since Yoda and the Jedi Council accepted Kota, we can safely assume that he met one or more of the listed qualities. Nothing is known of his family, but given that his planet is ravaged by war, perhaps we can assume that he had no family to leave behind. He has been fighting since the age of ten, so perhaps emotional control wasn't an issue.

It should also be noted that Yoda took it upon himself to train Kota - perhaps a sign that the 18-year-old needed a firmer hand or additional training due to his age.